# Using & Filtering Data with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm coding a simple website and currently I'm working on the User System. I coded a Login & Register and want to show the saved data to the specific user. Example: I get an ID when I log-in, now I want to receive all the data that is saved in the DB on my own ID. I don't have an idea how to do that and appreciate every little help. I'm able to show the User ID because it's saved in the Sessions, but no other data.

Everything I got at the moment, is a script that shows me the whole DB.

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=betaddicted', 'root', '' );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

foreach( $results as $row ){
  print_r( $row );
}
```

Thanks Guys!

Comment: *I'm able to show the User ID because it's saved in the Sessions* ; Take that ID and send it to your query. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=2`

Comment: The Script looks like this: Array ( [id] => 2 [email] => a@mail.com [passwort] => $2y$10$vK5.S73Mv708FnGyKOeP6FSkqYxNpE5AO [nickname] => Ari 2 [created_at] => 2016-11-07 19:15:55 [updated_at] => ) Array ( [id] => 3 [email] => an@email.com [passwort] => $2y$10$6mfIhFxV43MTymqteK7p18QEZYGVBhRAHp/RKC [nickname] => Ari [created_at] => 2016-11-07 21:20:39 [updated_at] => )

Comment: Thanks Hanky, that would not be the way I want it because the User ID is variable.

Comment: Of course that is just a hint. Replace that 2 with your variable

Comment: How? I'm a total noob in this case..

Comment: Make your query become `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?`  then on your `execute` call send it the variable value like this `$query->execute(array($_SESSION["id"]));` or whatever index contains your session user ID. Then watch magic unfold :P

Comment: Like this? 

$userdata = $pdo->prepare("SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$exeuserdata = $userdata->execute(array($_SESSION["userid"]));

echo $userdata;


I get:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\kode.resp\HTML\test123.php on line 57

Comment: Leave rest of the code same. Just change the query line and execute line

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=betaddicted', 'root', '' );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where id = ?";
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->bindValue(1,$_SESSION['id']);
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

foreach( $results as $row ){
  print_r($row );
}
```